# Understand how to prove by induction $\sum_{k=0}^n{{(-1)^k}{\binom nk}{k^m}}$

Tags: induction

I want to understand how do you prove by induction: $\sum_{k=0}^n{{(-1)^k}{\binom nk}{k^m}}=0$ where $0 \leq m < n$.

As far as I understood I have to:

- Prove the initial case $n = 1$
- Assume the hypothesis $\sum_{k=0}^n{{(-1)^k}{\binom nk}{k^m}}=0$
- Find for $n+1$, and here it's where I am stuck. I do not understand how can I manipulate the expression in order to solve the problem.

Could someone help me understand how to achieve this or point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you heard abot the finite differences? See, e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: On the other hand, you can try to prove by induction (on $n$) that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}f(k)=0$ for any polynomial $f$ of the degree $\deg f<n$ (hint: consider $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$).